# Month gets updated on adding minutes to Javascript Date Object

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm adding Time in Javascript Date object and month gets increased by 1.
Any idea what exactly is wrong in the logic. [image]

```js
var add_minutes =  function (dt, minutes) {
    return new Date(dt.getTime() + minutes*60000);
}
console.log(add_minutes(new Date(2014,10,2), 30).toString());
```

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/w3resource/pen/MXrPXg)

Comment: Time gets updated as expected but the problem is with month getting increased by 1.

Comment: That's obvious because the month in JS starts from 0. So for that case 10 is Nov not  Oct.

Comment: in javascript, month 0 is january, not 1. consequently, month 10 in javascript is november, not october

Comment: Try logging the date you've provided like `console.log(new Date(2014,10,2))`, You'll get `"2014-11-01T18:30:00.000Z"`. That is because month value starts from zero. If you need January, you have to give 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The month parameter is zero-indexed. Thus, new Date(2014,0,1) is January 1, and new Date(2014,11,1) is December 1.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Specifically,

> new Date(year, **monthIndex** [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [,
>   milliseconds]]]]]);

Also note that Date.getMonth() returns a zero-indexed month while Date.getDate() returns the day of the month as-is.

```js
var date = new Date(2014, 0, 10);

console.log("Date:" + date.toLocaleString("en-US"));
console.log("getMonth(): " + date.getMonth());
console.log("getDate(): " + date.getDate());
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is OK. The thing is, that in `Date()` the months are counted from `0`, so `10` is not October, it's November. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 1):

It's because month is zero-indexed. Try logging `new Date(2014,10,2).toString()`. 10 means November.